# How to check if a file is compressed in R

Tags: r

What is the best way in `R` to determine if a file is or isn't compressed? Is there any particular function to check that? 
I am asking about something different than looking at filename extension e.g.

```
grepl("^.*(.gz|.bz2|.tar|.zip|.tgz|.gzip|.7z)[[:space:]]*$", filename)
```

Comment: It is not generally possible to say whether a file is compressed (or indeed at all which format it is in). All you can do is test for known byte patterns at the start of the file, but this not really any more reliable than checking the file extension.

Comment: Why do you want to know this in `R`? What's your end goal?

Comment: fread() from the bioconductor package data.table doesn't take compressed file as an input argument

Answer (score 4):

In R, do this:

```
filetype = summary( file('yourfile.gz') )$class
```

If it's gzipped, `filetype` will be `gzfile`

**Note: you may also want to assign file to a variable and close the connection after**

```
filetype <- function(path){
    f = file(path)
    ext = summary(f)$class
    close.connection(f)
    ext
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux (or similar) you can use the `file` command.  E.g.

```
file filename
```

This will tell you useful information about a whole range of formats including, for example, if the file is compressed with `gzip` (one of the formats R can read directly).

Comment: In R, this would be `system("file filename")`

Answer (score 1):

If you have java installed, you can use the free tool [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to probe the metadata of a file.

Setup after download:

```
alias tika='java -jar /opt/java_shared/tika/tika-app-1.7.jar'
```

parse a file (slow, takes ~5 seconds)

```
tika -m chroma-1.15.tar.bz2

Content-Length: 2690725
Content-Type: application/x-bzip2
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.CompressorParser
resourceName: chroma-1.15.tar.bz2
```

Another example:

```
echo "hi there" > notazipfile.zip 

tika -m notazipfile.zip 

Content-Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser
resourceName: notazipfile.zip
```

There is a help page:

```
tika --help
```

Long list:

```
tika --list-supported-types | grep -C 3 bzip2

application/x-bzip
  supertype: application/octet-stream
  parser:    org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.CompressorParser
```

Again: Probing large files can take a while.

Note there exists a website where someone started to create an R interface, but this web page is from 2012, and seems to be inactive:
https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/r-tika/